# View the weight of the products in the invoice

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, custom, invoice, pdf

I need to show the weight of the products in the invoice PDF.

I modified the following files:

```
Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php
Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
```

and:

```
Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/DefaultShipment.php
Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/DefaultInvoice.php
```

In `DefaultShipment.php` works `$item->getWeight()` perfectly.
In `DefaultInvoice.php` there is not `$item->getWeight()`.

How can i recover the weight of the products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$item` within the DefaultShipment class is an instance of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Item` while `$item` in DefaultInvoice is `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Item`.

The data model for `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Item` below:
[image: Shipment Item Table]

Compared to the data model for `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Item`:
[image: Invoice Item Table]

The problem you're running into is the `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Item` does not contain the product weight. I didn't see a direct method of loading the product model from `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Item` so within whatever class you create for changing the behavior of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\DefaultInvoice.php` you'll need to inject `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` as a dependency, ie:

```
<?php
namspace Vendor\Module\PluginOrObserver;

class MyPluginOrObserver
{
  ...
  protected $_productRepository;
  ...

  public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    ...
  ) {
    ...
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    ...
  }
```

From there you can load the product and subsequently the weight with:

```
/** @var Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Item $item **/
$product = $this->_productRepository->getById($item->getProductId());
$weight = $product->getWeight();
```

All this ignores the issue that not all invoice items can be shipped and won't always have a weight.

Comment: You are a great one, it works perfectly! `$product = $this->_productRepository->getById($item->getProductId());
        $weight = $product->getWeight();
        $lines[0][] = ['text' => number_format($weight, 2, '.', '') .' kg', 'feed' => 445, 'align' => 'right'];`